# Python Speech Recognizer TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, machine-learning, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I am using the Speech Recognizer code in Python 3.6 consisting of Hidden Markov Models (HMM).
The training data (input folders) consisting of `.wav` files are organized as

```
train
   pineapple
   apple
   banana
   orange
   kiwi
   peach
   lime
```

Similar pattern is used for the `test` data folder.

The code is run from the command prompt:

```
python Speech-Recognizer.py --input-folder train
```

The code is pasted below:

```
import os
import argparse

import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
from hmmlearn import hmm
from python_speech_features import mfcc

# Function to parse input arguments
def build_arg_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Trains the HMM classifier')
    parser.add_argument("--input-folder", dest="input_folder", required=True,
                        help="Input folder containing the audio files in subfolders")
    return parser


# Class to handle all HMM related processing
class HMMTrainer(object):
    def __init__(self, model_name='GaussianHMM', n_components=4, cov_type='diag', n_iter=1000):
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.cov_type = cov_type
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.models = []

        if self.model_name == 'GaussianHMM':
            self.model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=self.n_components,
                                         covariance_type=self.cov_type, n_iter=self.n_iter)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Invalid model type')

    # X is a 2D numpy array where each row is 13D
    def train(self, X):
        np.seterr(all='ignore')
        self.models.append(self.model.fit(X))

    # Run the model on input data
    def get_score(self, input_data):
        return self.model.score(input_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = build_arg_parser().parse_args()
    input_folder = args.input_folder

    hmm_models = []

    # Parse the input directory
    for dirname in os.listdir(input_folder):
        # Get the name of the subfolder
        subfolder = os.path.join(input_folder, dirname)

        if not os.path.isdir(subfolder):
            continue

        # Extract the label
        label = subfolder[subfolder.rfind('/') + 1:]

        # Initialize variables
        X = np.array([])
        y_words = []

        # Iterate through the audio files (leaving 1 file for testing in each class)
        for filename in [x for x in os.listdir(subfolder) if x.endswith('.wav')][:-1]:
            # Read the input file
            filepath = os.path.join(subfolder, filename)
            sampling_freq, audio = wavfile.read(filepath)

            # Extract MFCC features
            mfcc_features = mfcc(audio, sampling_freq)

            # Append to the variable X
            if len(X) == 0:
                X = mfcc_features
            else:
                X = np.append(X, mfcc_features, axis=0)

            # Append the label
            y_words.append(label)

        print('X.shape =', X.shape)
        # Train and save HMM model
        hmm_trainer = HMMTrainer()
        hmm_trainer.train(X)
        hmm_models.append((hmm_trainer, label))
        hmm_trainer = None

    # Test files
    input_files = [
        'test/pineapple/pineapple15.wav',
        'test/orange/orange15.wav',
        'test/apple/apple15.wav',
        'test/kiwi/kiwi15.wav'
    ]

    # Classify input data
    for input_file in input_files:
        # Read input file
        sampling_freq, audio = wavfile.read(input_file)

        # Extract MFCC features
        mfcc_features = mfcc(audio, sampling_freq)

        # Define variables
        max_score = None
        output_label = None

        # Iterate through all HMM models and pick
        # the one with the highest score
        for item in hmm_models:
            hmm_model, label = item
            score = hmm_model.get_score(mfcc_features)
            if score > max_score:
                max_score = score
                output_label = label

        # Print the output
        print("\nTrue:", input_file[input_file.find('/') + 1:input_file.rfind('/')])
        print("Predicted:", output_label)
```

I get the following error while running the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Speech-Recognizer.py", line 113, in <module>
    if score > max_score:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        max_score = None
...
            if score > max_score:
```

You're trying to compare a float to None.

How about max_score = 0 instead of max_score = None?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since asking the question but I think I've found a solution, as I've also encountered this problem. This particular code is taken from Prateek Joshi's book for ML in Python (2.7). Since nowadays many people use 3.x, the Author's code might not be working properly in our environments. I see that you've already changed the name of library and *print()* functions, however for the code to fully work you should try:

```
# Define variables
    max_score = -np.inf
    output_label = None
```

Then it should work. In fact you can't compare float with None, but using np.inf solves the issue and the HMM work properly. Tested in PyCharm 2018.3.2 on macOS Mojave.